# Delete "updated" image after 5 day Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, last-modified, period

I use this code for show updated post. (if post updated show this image).

```
 <?php if (get_the_modified_time('U') > get_the_time('U')) { ?>
 <img class="update" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/update.png" alt="Updated">
```

Now i want after 5 day this "Updated image" deleted from post. and when i again update post this image again add to post ...(repeat this action).

How do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use date_diff() function for finding days difference between 2 dates. Please refer reference [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp) for further details...

Let me know if I can help you further....

Comment: This code for difference between 2 dates .how delete after x day and again add when i updated post in wordpress !?